# Converting/wrapping h264 video stream into MPEG2 TS

Tags: c++

I am reading in an mp4 file which I can demux. The file contains h264 video stream. I want to be able to wrap the h264 video stream in mpeg2 ts such that I can pass it onto other parts of the system as mpeg2 ts or even writing it into a new file as mpeg2 ts.
Any pointers would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: doom9 forum is your friend :)

Answer (score 2):

I recommend [FFMPEG](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/) for this task.  Here are some example uses for format [conversions](http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/19-ffmpeg-commands-for-all-needs)

Answer (score 1):

[tsMuxeR](http://www.videohelp.com/tools/tsMuxeR) was built for this purpose.

If you have troubles with that tool, try [TsRemux](http://www.videohelp.com/tools/TsRemux).